# How to add a class to the <html> element?

Tags: html, headers

I'm using the X-Theme in Wordpress and I ran into an issue where I needed a CSS class in the `<html>` tag, but only on one page. This is the code I added into my child theme header file:

```
<!-- If page#=103, add this class -->
<?php
    if( is_page( 103 ) ) {
        ?>
        <html class="html-homepage">
        <?php
    }
?>
```

The code went into the _header.php file and appears to be working with no issues.

My question is wondering if this method will break anything or if this is a super hacky way of doing this? I was unable to find a different solution that worked for me.

It looks like since Wordpress is doing the processing, it should be fine, but I wanted to make sure that this won't interfere with other Wordpress functionality.

Thanks!

**Edit:** The code I added is in the child theme files, not the Wordpress core files.

Comment: This looks useful: `add_filter( 'language_attributes'` https://gist.github.com/nickdavis/73d91d674b843b77a1cd0a21f9c0353a

Comment: @admcfajn Yeah, I saw that, but that seems kind of hacky, and some people reported that it can break in some themes.

Comment: I can see where it would cause concern. Personally I'd add the classes for the html-element to a string managed by the if-statement, rather than wrapping the whole element in the parenthesis (as it would "bloat" less when adding more conditions) ex: `$classes="";if($post->post_name === 'blog'){$classes .= 'blog'} echo '<html class="'.$classes.'">'; Could you use the [body_class](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/body_class/) function? You could maybe tack that onto the html-element instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way of adding the class. Replace `blog` withe the slug of the page. Example - This class will be added only on `example.com/blog`. Put this code in your `header.php`

```
<?php if($post->post_name === 'blog'){ ?>
    <html class="html-homepage">
<?php } else { ?>
    <html>
<?php ?>
```

Comment: So what makes this a safer approach than the code I used? I'm not trying to be mean, I just want to understand so I can know moving forward.

Comment: @MatthewJohnston I find it easier to see what page it will display on if I go look through the code a month or 6 months from now. Plus are you including an `<html>` still if that if doesn't come back true?

Comment: I have a comment on the code, so that's not an issue. And yes, it passes an html tag if that condition fails.

Comment: You also already have the `$post` variable. So one less function/query to database  with this approach.

Comment: `is_page()` isn't going to query the database.

Comment: @JacobPeattie my bad. I meant as additional logic

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that it is 'legal' (or effective) to have a class assigned to the html tag.  **Added** Well, a bit more research indicates that the HTML tag can have attributes like a style or class, so it can be done. Just not sure why you would add styles to the HTML tag rather than the BODY tag.

**Original Answer**

What I think you need is something to add to the 'body' class for a specific page. See the answer to this similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2466073/add-a-custom-class-name-to-wordpress-body-tag .

And, one should not normally (or never) modify theme files (or WP core code). You should use a Child Theme to adjust theme actions. That way, you can add a filter to the Child Theme's function.php file, and any changes you make will not be overwritten with a theme or WP update.

Using the solution in the above related question assumes that your theme is using the body_class function properly. Which is another reason why a Child Theme is a better solution - you can ensure that the theme will use the body_class function in the page output.

Comment: Sorry, I should clarify: This code I added is in the _header.php file for my child theme. I'm not editing the Wordpress core files directly.

Also, I definitely do need the class attached to the '<html>' element, not the body element.